# Express and Node Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am running an application using `express`. I am trying to use `mongoose` in a node application. I have all dependencies installed.

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self';font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https:; style-src 'self' ; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Node application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is sample page</h1>
    <script src="watchData.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//setting middleware
app.use(express.static('public')); //Serves resources from public folder
app.listen(5000);
```

watchData.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

`watchData.js` and `index.html` is in `public` folder. I am getting following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at watchData.js:1
(anonymous) @ watchData.js:1
```

in line 1 which is `const mongoose = require('mongoose')`

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs when u are trying to run node applications on browser. You can use a tool named browserify to convert node modules to simple scripts that you can define in script tags. Here are some useful links you can follow.
NPM official link for documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify
Video tutorial:
https://youtu.be/CTAa8IcQh1U

Answer (score 0):

There are some concepts here that are not correctly scoped between client and server. `watchData.js` should be part of the node app on the server side, but is instead being served as a static asset which the client (browser) tries and fails to run as a script.

The browser can't directly call functions or run scripts from in the node app. It can communicate with the node app by making HTTP requests to URLs the node app exposes using express.

I recommend first going through the [example app for express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html), then adding [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/) queries once you have static content working correctly.